# maven build fails after adding jar to artifatory .m2/repository do not contain the jar file

Tags: java, maven, grails, intellij-idea, artifactory

I tried to add jasperreports.jar file to the artifactory under  libs-release-local:net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.0.1/jasperreports-5.0.1.jar and the deployment was successful.

pom.xml dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jasperreports-htmlcomponent</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports-htmlcomponent</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <!--version>5.1.0</version-->
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But when I try to run the application from Intellij, I get the error path to dependency
Both the jar files are present in the artifactory but is not getting recognized.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.864 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-25T15:51:47-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.3.4:run-app (default-cli) on project MPF-SalesQuote: Failed to create classpath for Grails execution. Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js1 from/to metasystems-snapshots (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/metasystems-snapshot): Failed to transfer file: http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/metasystems-snapshot/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js1/itext-2.1.7.js1.jar. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: The repository 'metasystems-snapshot' rejected the artifact 'metasystems-snapshot:com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js1/itext-2.1.7.js1.jar' due to its snapshot/release handling policy..
[ERROR] com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] metasystems-snapshots (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/metasystems-snapshot, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] metasystems-release (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/metasystems-release, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] local-releases (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] grails (http://repo.grails.org/grails/core, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] grails-plugins (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] Metasystems Inc. (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] central-mirror (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/remote-repos, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) com.metasystems:MPF-SalesQuote:grails-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 2) net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:5.0.1
[ERROR] 3) com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoEx
```

ecutionException

Answer (score 1):

Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: The repository 'metasystems-snapshot' rejected the artifact 'metasystems-snapshot:com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js1/itext-2.1.7.js1.jar' due to its snapshot/release handling policy..

As Error Code 409 suggests, you are trying to deploy a snapshot version into a release only repository. Hence the conflict. Select a snapshot repository instead of a release one in your pom.xml or select a release library rather than the snapshot library for your release version.

Comment: I kinda thought the same, but the error message seems to suggest the repo supports both snapshot/release:

[ERROR] metasystems-snapshots (http://javaguru.metasystems.com:8081/artifactory/metasystems-snapshot, releases=true, snapshots=true),

Is this coming back from the remote host, or defined locally?

Comment: btw... I think the issue is on pulling the artifact during the run-app goal and not on deploy

Comment: yes, it is a snapshot version that says <version>1.0.SNAPSHOT</Version> in pom.xml. once i build the war using  grails -Dgrails.env=test war, i rename the war and deploy it in the test server. Should I change the version to "RELEASE"? Is there anything specific I need to do.

Comment: I have both snapshot and release repositories mentioned in pom.xml

Comment: @coffeeaddict This error comes only from remote host. Locally, it is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried if it works as release? If so, perhaps you need to configure your remote host to support snapshots

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me , BTW it made deploy slower due to downloading **extra** repositories.

[Jasper Library download forbidden when running maven: mvn package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369940/944593)

Sorry Can i post some one answer from other question ( here is the solution )
**Please add below repository** in your `pom.xml`,

```
<repositories> 
    <repository>
        <id>jasperreports</id>
        <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
        <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/t‌​hird-party-ce-artifa‌​cts/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```