# Jasper Library download forbidden when running maven: mvn package

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am downloading all libraries I need for my spring project in Intellij Idea. I am using maven: mvn package. All libraries succeeded, except for one that is forbidden:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project remax-service: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.qr.remax:remax-service:war:1.4.0: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.4.0 -> 
com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js5: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js5 from/to jaspersoft-third-party 
(http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/):
 Access denied to: http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js5/itext-2.1.7.js5.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
```

I put this http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js5/itext-2.1.7.js5.pom in my browser and I get
403 error code:

[image: Your client does not have permission to get URL /jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js5/itext-2.1.7.js5.pom from this server. That’s all we know.]

I think that it has to do with the blocked site's policy for my country. Anyway is there an alternative to do this???

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml showing this dependency, I am using below dependency from US and it works fine, `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Can you try adding repository in your pom.xml, `<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>jasperreports</id>
   <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
   <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>`

Comment: @AmitKBist post your las comment as answer to vote you up!!!!!

Comment: Done, please accept the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add below repository in your pom.xml,

```
<repositories> 
    <repository>
        <id>jasperreports</id>
        <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
        <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/t‌​hird-party-ce-artifa‌​cts/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Gives [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx: Failed to collect dependencies at xxx -> net.s f.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.12.2 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js7: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js7 from/to jr-ce-releases (http://jasperso ft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases): Transfer failed for http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js7/itext-2.1.7.js7.pom 308 Permanent Redirect

Comment: This repository seems obsolete now. Use https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-repo/ instead as state in the answer from Andre.

Answer (score 19):

I am updating with the latest information. Just use the code below:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
        <id> jaspersoft-repo</id>
        <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-repo</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Had the same problem with itext-2.1.7.js7. Tested it - works for me, as opposed to Amit's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also fixed this error: Blocked mirror for repositories: [jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/, default, releases+snapshots), jr-ce-releases (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases, default, releases+snapshots)]

Comment: Where should i add it in pom.xml?

Comment: Before <denepdencies></dependencies>

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your pom.xml file and after `</dependencies>`

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jasperreports</id>
          <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
          <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
```